# How can you code the teachers' preferences constraint for a Timetable application in Timefold Solver using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, constraints, timefold

Let's say that I have an application for generating a university timetable and I have as a  constraint a preference of some teachers to teach only in certain periods of a specific day. How can I implement that type of constraint in Timefold? What would be the best practices to add such situations in the scheduling algorithm in Spring Boot/Java?

I saw an example on the Timefold's GitHub Repo for the following scenario that may be similar to what I need: A teacher prefers to teach sequential lessons and dislikes gaps between lessons. And the code for this constraint looks like this:

```
Constraint teacherTimeEfficiency(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    // A teacher prefers to teach sequential lessons and dislikes gaps between lessons.
    return constraintFactory
            .forEachUniquePair(Lesson.class,
                    Joiners.equal(Lesson::getTeacher),
                    Joiners.equal((lesson) -> lesson.getTimeslot().getDayOfWeek()))
            .filter((lesson1, lesson2) -> {
                Duration between = Duration.between(lesson1.getTimeslot().getEndTime(),
                        lesson2.getTimeslot().getStartTime());
                return !between.isNegative() && between.compareTo(Duration.ofMinutes(30)) <= 0;
            })
            .reward(HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT)
            .justifyWith((lesson1, lesson2, score) -> new TeacherTimeEfficiencyJustification(lesson1.getTeacher(), lesson1, lesson2))
            .asConstraint("Teacher time efficiency");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the exact `Timeslots` that are preferred? If so, I would model `Teacher` like this:

```java
// preferredTimeslots is nullable
public record Teacher(String name, List<Timeslot> preferredTimeslots) {}
```

And then the constraint would be

```
Constraint maximizePreferredTimeslotAssignments(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(Lesson.class)
               .join(Teacher.class, Joiners.equal(Lesson::getTeacher, Function.identity()))
               .filter((lesson, teacher) -> teacher.preferredTimeslots() != null && !teacher.preferredTimeslots().contains(lesson.getTimeslot()))
               .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT)
               .asConstraint("Teacher was assigned unpreferred timeslot");
}
```

This will penalize ALL non-preferred timeslot assignments for a `Teacher` (provided the `Teacher` has preferred timeslots). If a `Teacher` has no preferred timeslots on Monday, and you do not want to penalize all Monday assignments for that teacher, you would want to change the `List<Timeslot>` to a `Map<DayOfWeek, List<Timeslot>>` (with the corresponding change in the filter):

```java
(lesson, teacher) -> teacher.preferredTimeslots().get(lesson.getTimeslot().getDayOfWeek()) != null && !teacher.preferredTimeslots().get(lesson.getTimeslot().getDayOfWeek()).contains(lesson.getTimeslot())
```

Comment: If I don't have a preferred timeslot on Monday, can't I consider that the timeslot will be something like whenever between 8:00 AM and 8:00 PM (i.e. all classes take place only in that interval, so that teacher could be assigned to any interval, if there is a course on the respective day)?

Comment: Then I recommend the Map approach; the `teacher.preferredTimeslots().get(lesson.getTimeslot().getDayOfWeek()) != null`  in the filter means that if a teacher does not have a preferred timeslot on a particular day, the constraint will not be triggered.

Comment: (Using intervals are indeed possible, but it will be a bit more work than just checking Timeslot instances, since you need to write a function that checks if a Timeslot matches an interval; you would probably want to check if a preferred interval contains the entire lesson's timeslot (i.e. teacher.preferredTimeslots().containsTimeslot(lesson.getTimeslot()), where `containsTimeslot` is your "interval contains" function))